# How to save One2many fields values?

Tags: odoo, odoo-13, one2many

I am adding custom **One2many** field in **sale.order** form view just below the **sale.order.line**.

I am computing values **on_change** it is displaying values but when I am going to save the sales order it is generating error that

> ValueError: Wrong value for tax.lines.order_id: sale.order(24,)

**Python:**

```
class SaleOrderInherit(models.Model):
_inherit = ['sale.order']

tax_line = fields.One2many('tax.lines', 'order_id', states={'cancel': [('readonly', True)], 'done': [('readonly', True)]}, copy=True, auto_join=True)

@on.change('partner_id')
def calculating_tax(self):
    //After some code
    self.env['tax.lines'].create({
              'tax_id': tax['tid'],
              'name': tax['name'],
              'amount': tax['tax'],
              'order_id': self.id
       })


class TaxLines(models.Model):
_name = 'tax.lines'

tax_id = fields.Char('Tax Id')
name = fields.Char('Tax Name')
amount = fields.Char('Tax Amount')
order_id = fields.Many2one('sale.order', string='Tax Report', ondelete='cascade', index=True, copy=False)
```

Because I am creating one2many field before creating the order.
But is there any way to get rid of this problem.

Edit:
Error after replacing my code with `Charif DZ` code:

[image]

Comment: Adam the relation ship won't work like this,  many2one is pointed to account.move and the one2many is in sale.order ?!!

Comment: Yeah but it was a typing mistake...

Comment: BTW is it possible to create one2many field in sale.order without fkey? I am asking because without fkey how values relate to sale.order and sale.order without confirming or saving is not showing its id

Comment: It's not possible you must specify the inverse_name in one2many and that field should be a valid m2o field I don't know what you need exactly I didn't understand you. You can contact me in LinkedIn I remember that you asked me to contact you before. And my code work I think it deserve at least an up vote

Comment: @CharifDZ haha! why not, sorry for delay actually i am confused that is why.

Comment: Actually i want to print list of custom taxes applied to a sales order, taxes may be multiple or a single. that is why i am looking for one2many. but for creating one2many it is asking fkey.

Comment: So it's just for UI make it compute field with store=False I think It will not cause a problem on save because nothing will be saved in database, and try to make it many2many I think it's easier

Comment: Finally many2many did my work :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never create records in onchange events they are immidiatly saved in database what if the user decided to cancel the order, instead of create use new with create an object but doesn't save it in database.

```py
       def calculating_tax(self):
              //After some code
              # to add record to your o2m use `|` oprator
              # if you want to clear record before start adding new records make sure to empty your field first by an empty record set like this 
              # self.tax_line = self.env['tax.lines']  do this before the for loop that is used to fill-up the field not put it inside or you will get only the last record 
              self.tax_line |=   self.env['tax.lines'].new({
                       'tax_id': tax['tid'],
                       'name': tax['name'],
                        'amount': tax['tax'],
                        # 'order_id': self.id remove the many2one because it's handled automaticly by the one2many
                  })
```

I hope this help you good luck

Comment: then what to do for saving the record? because it is giving me error: tax.lines (tax.lines), Constraint: tax_lines_order_id_fkey

Comment: I didn't try y'it before in o2m field try to put back the order_id : self.id

Comment: Is these appear in the new method call, or when you save the record?

Comment: tried but nothing...i just replaced my code with your code it is showing values but when i clicked on save or confirm button it is giving error

Comment: Can you put the stacktrace of the error in your question please?

Comment: Update my question

Comment: Okay lets do it the old way using X2many commands the problem with this technique that if you want to keep the old records you should add them to the list using command 4, I hope that you don't need that in most cases you don't